# Rendering DateTime to dd/mm/yyyy format in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to figure out how to render a DateTime value to short string or in the format of dd/mm/yyyy. I tried DateCreated.Value.ToShortDateString() and DateCreated.ToShortDateString(), but it doesn't seemed defined for a DataTable

My current output looks like 2017-04-23T17:39:20.687

How can I render it like dd/mm/yyyy in a DataTable?

```
@model IEnumerable<TestApp.Models.Announcement>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Announcement List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AnnouncementList</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("New Announcement", "New", "Annoucement", null, new {@class = "btn btn-primary"})


<table id="announcement" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $("#announcement").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/announcements",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "title",
                        render: function(data, type, announcement) {
                            return announcement.title;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "description",
                        render: function(data, type, announcement) {
                            return announcement.description;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "dateCreated",
                        render: function(data, type, announcement) {
                            return announcement.dateCreated;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function(data) {
                            return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-announcement-id=" +
                                data +
                                ">Delete</button>";
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });


            $("#announcement").on("click",
                ".js-delete",
                function() {
                    var button = $(this);

                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this annoucement?",
                        function(result) {
                            if (result) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/api/announcement/" + button.attr("data-annoucement-id"),
                                    method: "DELETE",
                                    success: function() {
                                        table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                });
        });
    </script>


}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApp.Models
{
    public class Announcement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Title { get; set; }


[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
     //   public bool? SendEmail { get; set; }

    }
}
```

CodingYoshi's posted answer

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $("#announcement").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/announcements",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "title",
                        render: function(data, type, announcement) {
                            return announcement.title;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "description",
                        render: function(data, type, announcement) {
                            return announcement.description;
                        }
                    },
                    {
            data: "dateCreated", //also tried putting data: dateCreatedFormatted here too:
                        render: function (data, type, announcement) {
                            return announcement.dateCreatedFormatted;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function(data) {
                            return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-announcement-id=" +
                                data +
                                ">Delete</button>";
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });


            $("#announcement").on("click",
                ".js-delete",
                function() {
                    var button = $(this);

                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this annoucement?",
                        function(result) {
                            if (result) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/api/announcement/" + button.attr("data-annoucement-id"),
                                    method: "DELETE",
                                    success: function() {
                                        table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                });
        });
    </script>
```

earloc's posted answer

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $("#announcement").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/announcements",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "title",
                        render: function(data, type, announcement) {
                            return announcement.title;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "description",
                        render: function(data, type, announcement) {
                            return announcement.description;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "dateCreated",
                        render: function (data, type, announcement) {
                            return announcement.FormattedDate;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function(data) {
                            return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-announcement-id=" +
                                data +
                                ">Delete</button>";
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });


            $("#announcement").on("click",
                ".js-delete",
                function() {
                    var button = $(this);

                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this annoucement?",
                        function(result) {
                            if (result) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/api/announcement/" + button.attr("data-annoucement-id"),
                                    method: "DELETE",
                                    success: function() {
                                        table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                });
        });
    </script>
```

and I put this

```
 public string FormattedDate => DateCreated.ToShortDateString();


 public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

in model

Comment: You could format the date in the client-side code that renders the DataTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you´re mixing technologies here!

Either, provide a formatted string-representation in your Model like (C# 6 Syntax):

```
public string FormattedDate => DateCreated.ToShortDateString()
```

and pull this property in JavaScript via:

```
columns: [
                {
                    data: "dateCreated",
                    render: function(data, type, announcement) {
                        return announcement.FormattedDate;
                    }
                },
```

or, as Maria suggested, format the date directly on the client-side using techniques like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) or with help of e.g.: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

(Tha Client-Side JavaScript does not know anything about "ToShortDateString"-Method on a date...)

Comment: For this I'm getting the error: DataTables warning: table id=announcement - Requested unknown parameter 'dateCreated' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4 See code above for reference.

Comment: As both answers Are kind of correct, i would appreciate an upvote .

Answer (score 3):

Add this property to your model:

```
public string DateCreatedFormatted { get { return this.DateCreated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); } }
```

Then bind to this property in your JavaScript code.

Comment: It should be "dd/MM/yyyy". Lowercase mm means minutes, not months.

Comment: I tried this and put it in to the table, but got the following error. See added code above for reference DataTables warning: table id=announcement - Requested unknown parameter 'dateCreatedFormatted' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: @andy javascript is case sensitive so you must use `DateCreatedFormatted`

Comment: I wrote it in camel case because I added code that formats everything in camelcase and thought that's how I would need to add it in webapiconfig.cs    *var settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
            settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;*

Comment: I figured out the issue. I was using Dto model and didn't put the formatted public string line in there so it didn't see it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post it is a old. I am show my solution working on asp.net Core 3.1 environment.
My objective was to display a datetime value obtained from a database column with a datetime2(2) datatype, in a more clear format like dd-mm-yy HH:mm.

Required scripts:

```
 <script src="~/js/datagrid/datatables/datatables.bundle.js"></script>
 <script src="~/js/dependency/moment/moment.js"></script>
```

Solution shortcut:

```
   columns: [
            { title: "Username", data: "username" },
            {
                title: "Registration Date",
                data: "enrollmentTimeStamp",
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return moment(data).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
                }
            },
        ],
```

Good luck!